# Mobx store update when React props change

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm creating a generic **react component**, I'm using **mobx** internally to control the component state. What I need to achieve is besides to keep all business logic in Store, when the user change the **showSomething** prop, the store should know it so **fetchSomeStuffs** runs and change **anotherThing**.

```
// Application using the component
@observer
class MyApplication extends React.Component {
  @observable
  showSomething = false;

  changeThings = () => {
    this.showSomething = true;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.changeThings}>Change Show Something</button>
        <MyComponent showSomething={showSomething} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class Store {
  @observable
  showSomething = false;

  @observable
  anotherThing = [];

  @action
  setShowSomething = value => {
    this.showSomething = value;
  };

  // I'll dispose this later...
  fetchSomeStuffs = autorun(() => {
    const { showSomething } = this;

    // Update some other stuffs
    if (showSomething) {
      this.anotherThing = [1, 2, 3];
    } else {
      this.anotherThing = [];
    }
  });
}

@observer
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    showSomething: PropTypes.bool
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.store = new Store();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { setShowSomething } = this.store;
    this.setSomethingDispose = autorun(() =>
      setShowSomething(this.props.showSomething)
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setSomethingDispose();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        <MySubComponent />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

@inject("store")
@observer
class MySubComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { showSomething, anotherThing } = this.props.store;
    return (
      <div>
        MySubComponent
        {showSomething && "Something is finally showing"}
        {anotherThing.map((r, i) => {
          return <div key={i}>{r}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the way i found to achieve it, all the logic is in the Store and I use an **autorun** in the **componentDidMount** of my main component to always keep the **showSomething** variable of the store the same as the prop.
My doubt here is if this is a good practice or if there are better ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way, using computed values.

One pattern is to use a *private* variable to hold the values and a computed value to expose what you want.

using this pattern you can implement list filters and all sorts of dynamic computations with a lot of agility, since MobX optimizes all computed values.

Just remember that to access a computed value you just have to read it as a property, not a function.

Ex:

```
// good
store.anotherThing

// bad
store.anotherThing()
```

```js
class Store {
  @observable
  showSomething = false;

  @observable
  _anotherThing = [];

  @action
  setShowSomething = value => {
    this.showSomething = value;
  };

  @computed get anotherThing() {
    const { showSomething } = this;

    // Update some other stuffs
    if (showSomething) {
      this._anotherThing = [1, 2, 3];
    } else {
      this._anotherThing = [];
    }
  }
}
```